# Can this PHP framework be identified?

Tags: php, frameworks

I just got a few PHP projects which are using a similar kind of framework but I can't tell which one. I have experienced some Code Igniter, Django and Rails before but I can't pinpoint that specific framework. I'm looking through the PHP files for any indications of its origin but they seem to have been wiped out.  The person I'm helping has no clue in programming so he can't tell me where they come from.  It has the following directory structure for the project helloworld:

```
helloworld/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    modules/
        hi/
            hi.php
        home.php
    system/
        conf.inc.php
        functions/
    theme/
        default/
            images/
            js/
            templates/
                home.tpl
```

For the above, it seems that the Controller code is under the modules folder. Can someone also tell me which PHP template engine is being used for the following syntax? The template is accessed in the Controller code(home.php) like the following:

```
$tpl = new template;
$tpl -> Load("!theme/{$GLOBALS["THEME"]}/templates/home.tpl");
$tpl -> GetObjects();

// more PHP codes  here

$tpl -> CleanZones();
$tpl -> Flush();
```

A sample View code:

```
<base href="{siteURL}/" target="_self" />
```

I'm not sure if the above is homebrew, customized version of an existing framework or an unmodified version of one of the many PHP frameworks out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing a [quick google keyword search](http://www.google.com.gt/search?q=tpl+template+GetObjects+CleanZones), it looks like code from [PHPizabi](http://www.phpizabi.net/) a "social networking platform"...

Comment: Thanks, in the long term, do you think it's worth keeping the code around or switch to a more supported framework?